# Guidline 4.1 - Copycats

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, game-development

So my app was rejected yesterday and I am not sure why exactly and what the reasons mean exactly.

Here is the message from the review team..

> Your app or its metadata appears to contain misleading content.
>
> Specifically, your app includes content that resembles Stevo The Mad
>   Man without the necessary authorization.
>
> Next Steps
>
> You may attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information
>   section in App Store Connect. In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the
>   Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that
>   submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the
>   termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of
>   your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your
>   documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the
>   review of your app.
>
> Alternatively, please remove the third-party content from your app and
>   its metadata

Now I should mention that Stevo The Mad Man is a influencer based in London and not to get mixed up with Steve-O. 
I am working on an official game for Stevo and we've been in constant communication during the development process.

Im just wondering did this game get rejected because there was no proof that I was allowed to make a game based on his likeliness?

Comment: I've voted to close because this isn't a programming question. Trying to convince Apple to distribute your application is entirely a business question about the details of your agreement with them, and [not something we can really help with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839), just like it wouldn't make sense to ask here about whether you should buy a billboard to advertise your software.

Comment: @Peter Cooper Jr yes but I wasn’t sure what the issue was and saw there was a few other general questions like this on here that got answers too so I thought it would be ok. Is stack overflow purely for programming only ???

Comment: Stuff that's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here is practical programming problems about code or involving tools primarily used by programmers. There are other [StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) focusing on other areas. Having this closed isn't us saying "you're bad" or anything, it's just that it doesn't really fit with our format. This question is only asking about how to interact with Apple to get them to distribute your product. There's not much we can do about that because [we're not Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,it got rejected becuase of that,to avoid this.

either delete the refernce,or
 re-upload and write a note in additional note,and provide a written letter from him, stating that the app is his,and he is allowing this content.

other than this they wont ever accept it.